# lambdas with the standard query operators

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

```
public delegate TResult Func<TArg0, TResult>(TArg0 arg0)  

Func<int, bool> myFunc = x => x == 5;
bool result = myFunc(4); // returns false of course
```

I do not understand this example.
What does this code mean?

```
public delegate TResult Func<TArg0, TResult>(TArg0 arg0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) definition, which matches any non-void method with single input argument. Your lambda function (i.e. anonymous method) matches this signature.

BTW you don't need to create this delegate - it already exists in .NET framework: 
[`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Comment: +1, I think this is a pretty good answer. I don't understand why you were downvoted either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read any tutorials about delegates so far?

The line means: A delegate type for functions which return a TResult and take a TArg0 argument. As this is a generic delegate you can assign various methods, the following would all be possible:

```
int Foo (int i);
double Foo (string str);
...
```

`TArg0 arg0` is a function parameter (parameter name: arg0, parameter type: generic, unknown at the moment). TArg0 is therefore *inferred* by the compiler as you actually use it, e.g. `double Foo(string str)` would set `TArg0 = string`.

Comment: Have you downvoted us for our answers? I'm going to adapt the answer for TArg0 arg0.

Comment: @JacekWojcik It's an argument with the type `TArg0`

Comment: @D.R. he can't downvote with only 10 rep, but... I like your answer and I don't understand why it was downvoted. +1